# Rails 4: HubSpot API error checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, hubspot

I am using the [Rails wrapper for the HubSpot API](https://github.com/adimichele/hubspot-ruby) and while I am able to successfully create contacts, I cannot seem to handle errors.

```
def createHubSpotContact(potential_client)
    puts "creating hubspot contact..."
    @potential_client = potential_client

    @first_name = @potential_client.name.split(" ").first || "N/A"
    @last_name = @potential_client.name.split(" ").last || "N/A"
    @phone = @potential_client.phone || "N/A"
    @email = @potential_client.email || "N/A"
    @referrer = @potential_client.referrer || "other"
    @city = Location.find(@potential_client.location_id).name || "N/A"
    @message = @potential_client.message || "N/A"

    contact = Hubspot::Contact.create!(@email, {
        firstname: @first_name,
        lastname: @last_name,
        phone: @phone,
        email: @email,
        referrer: @referrer,
        city: @city,
        message: @message
    })

    # What can I do to handle an error here?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bang method `create!` should raise an error if the contact is not valid. Therefore, you would never get past the create to handle the error.

Taking a look at the [gem source](https://github.com/adimichele/hubspot-ruby/blob/master/lib/hubspot/contact.rb#L28), the `create!` method calls the HubSpot API:

```
response = Hubspot::Connection.post_json(CREATE_CONTACT_PATH, params: {}, body: post_data )
```

In `Connection#post_json`,

```
raise(Hubspot::RequestError.new(response)) unless response.success?
```

If there is a problem creating the contact, a `RequestError` is raised. So, you can catch that:

```
begin
  contact = Hubspot::Contact.create!(@email, {
  ...

rescue Hubspot::RequestError
      # Handle an error here.
end
```

One way to handle this would be to return false from `createHubSpotContact`:

```
rescue Hubspot::RequestError
   return false
end
```

Then, you could use it with

```
if contact = createHubSpotContact(potential_client)
  ...
else
  #failure
end
```